# Coq: defining a function based on uniqueness and existence theorems

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

To isolate this issue as much as possible, suppose I begin a Coq session as follows.

```
Parameter A : Type.
Parameter B : Type.
Parameter P : A -> B -> Prop.

Axiom existence : forall a : A, exists b : B, P a b.
Axiom uniqueness : forall a : A, forall b b' : B, P a b -> P a b' -> b = b'.
```

From here, I want to define a function `f : A -> B` as the unique function for which `P a (f a)` is always true.

How can I do this? *Can* I do this? Obviously I ought to begin with something like

```
Definition f : A -> B.
  intro a.
  assert (E := existence a).
  assert (U := uniqueness a).
```

...but how do I actually write the function in terms of these hypotheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is not possible in your current setting.

The problem is that you can extract the b from your `existence` theorem, but this can only live in `Prop`.

So, I believe you either have to move `A` and `B` in `Prop`, or to move `existence` and `uniqueness` in `Set`.

This would result in either of these:

---

```
Parameter A : Prop.
Parameter B : Prop.
Parameter P : A -> B -> Prop.

Axiom existence : forall a : A, exists b : B, P a b.
Axiom uniqueness : forall a : A, forall b b' : B, P a b -> P a b' -> b = b'.

Definition f : A -> B.
  intro a. destruct (existence a) as [b _]. exact b.
Defined.
```

---

```
Parameter A : Set.
Parameter B : Set.
Parameter P : A -> B -> Prop.

Axiom existence : forall a : A, { b : B | P a b }.
Axiom uniqueness : forall a : A, forall b b' : B, P a b -> P a b' -> b = b'.

Definition f : A -> B.
  intro a. destruct (existence a) as [b _]. exact b.
Defined.
```

---

It is quite possible that neither of these is actually what you want. In that case, I would need more details to be able to help. It might be that you're willing to do something that is not possible in an intuitionistic setting.

PS: I am no expert.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept this answer. Your second example works for me, and in fact even works with `A` and `B` in `Type`. Thanks!